# What verb tense do I use in this question?

Tags: verbs, tenses

I had a student ask about verb tense in the following question. "Live" is used with "the President", but I can't figure out why I don't want to add the "s". It doesn't "sound" right to me and I can't explain *why*. 
Ex.-Is it important that the President *live* in the White House? OR Is it important that the President *lives* in the White House?

Comment: I would go with the subjunctive rather than the present simple.

Comment: I agree with Centaurus. Both are OK. The plain form "live" is head of the subjunctive clause while present tense "lives" heads the non-subjunctive content clause. The subjunctive is generally seen as the more formal alternant.

Comment: More formal in BE, not AE. Interesting paper on the subjunctive in current use: https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/25257/Finalxversion.Master.Vlasova.pdf?sequence=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is important that the President *live* in the White House.

The absence of the expected third personal singular ending *s* signals the use of the [present subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive), also called the *mandative* subjunctive used for states or actions desired, required, necessary, etc. The present subjunctive occurs only in *that*-clauses, though the relative pronoun may be omitted.

> It is imperative that she *leave* immediately.
>
> His parents suggested he *stay* a few days longer with his grandfather.

It is called *present* subjunctive because it is formed from the present tense of the verb, not because it describes events in present time. In the last sentence, the grandfather, parents, and son could be long dead.

> When the queen demanded [that he *march*](http://www.historyireland.com/early-modern-history-1500-1700/toy-boy-turned-traitor/) against Ulster, the heart of the insurrection, his army was too weak.

Using the present indicative lacks the sense of *should* of the subjunctive and only describes a general state or condition.

> It is important that the President *lives* in the White House.

If a state current *right now* is desired, then use the present progressive:

> It is important that the President *is living* in the White House.